# using statement for background worker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, using

I have been looking over several examples of backgroundworkers and I ran across code that looks similar to this

```
public class MyClass
{
  public MyClass()
  {
    using(BackgroundWorker _Worker = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerReportsProgress = true})
    {
      _Worker.DoWork += (s, args) =>
      {
        ...
      };
    }
    _Worker.RunWorkerAsync();
  }
}
```

I have not been using the "using" statment in my code like this.  I ran across something similar while using the Code Rush trial, which made me come back to this code and question if i should be doing this or not.  Please help me understand if/why this would be best practice.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `BackgroundWorker` does not need to be disposed, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542326/proper-way-to-dispose-of-a-backgroundworker/2542380#2542380). So there is no need to have the `using` clause

Answer (score 1):

Using the `using` keyword like that simply handles dispose for you.  Without it, you'd be constantly writing `try / catch / finally` blocks in order to make sure objects implementing IDisposable were disposed properly.

Also note that you can put multiple declarations in a using statement, if you have multiple objects that need to be disposed:

```
using (Font font3 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f), 
           font4 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f))
{
    // Use font3 and font4.
}
```

Here's the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on it.

Answer (score 1):

The `using` statement defines a scope that outside of which objects will be disposed. So it is just a convention by which the resources are disposed of automatically. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx),

> The using statement allows the programmer to specify when objects that
>   use resources should release them. The object provided to the using
>   statement must implement the IDisposable interface. This interface
>   provides the Dispose method, which should release the object's
>   resources.

It is perfectly acceptable in your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The using statement takes place of surrounding your code with a try/catch block.  But not everything can use the using statement; only objects that implement Dispose() can.